# How to add displays without re-rendering the whole component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm just new to Laravel and Vuejs. And I have this problem wherein the whole component is re-rendering when the "Load More" button is clicked or when scrolled down to the bottom. The button or scroll is just acting like a pagination, but all you can do is to load more or add more displays. My problem is how can i render the new displays without re-rendering the whole component.

I tried creating a variable wherein it will pass how many paginate will be displayed. Yes it does the work but the component is re-rendering and the size of the reply from the server gets larger and larger.

here's my script on my Vue component:

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['user','review_count'],
    data(){
        return{
            reviews: {},
            limit: 2,
            scrolledToBottom: false,
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.getReviews();
        this.scroll();
    },
    methods: {
        getReviews: function(page){
            axios.get('/datas/reviews?user='+ this.user + '&limit='+ this.limit)
            .then((response) =>{
                this.reviews = response.data.data;
            })
            .catch(()=>{
            });
        },
        countType: function(data, type) {
            return data.filter(function(value) { return value.type === type }).length;
        },
        loadMore: function(){
            this.limit+=6;
            this.getReviews();
        },
        scroll () {
            window.onscroll = () => {
                let bottomOfWindow = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop) + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight
                if (bottomOfWindow&&this.review_count>this.limit) {
                    this.loadMore();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

here's my controller:

```
public function reviews()
    {
        if($users = \Request::get('user')){
            if($limit = \Request::get('limit')){
        $reviews = Review::select(\DB::raw('id, product_id, review_rating, review_content'))
                        ->where('user_id', $users)
                        ->with('products:product_image,id,product_name')
                        ->with('activities')
                        ->orderBy('reviews.created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->paginate($limit);}}
        return $reviews;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without re render the whole component"? Could you share the component template, please? It can help me to get more context.

Comment: all i want to do is like a social media wall type of component wherein it will just add a new display instead of just re-render the whole component just to add new display

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is two things you need to do.

1/ in stead of increasing the limit eveytime, you should look into paging your results on the server, so you can ask the next page from your server.  Now, on each consecutive call you are fetching what you already had again, which will eliminate your goal of making this less stressful on your server

2/ in your client code obviously you need to support the paging as well, but also make sure you properly set your key on the looped elements.  VueJS used the key to determine whether it should rerender that particular element in the loop.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: thank you for you opinion sir, I've already come up with a solution just like your first opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own Question, the solution is using pagination. I just pushed all of the data from the server in an object every time it scrolled down.

here's my code for scroll down:

```
scroll () {
            window.onscroll = () => {
                let bottomOfWindow = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop) + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight
                if (bottomOfWindow&&this.review_count>this.reviews.length) {
                this.getReviews();
                }
            }
        }
```

here's my codes for getReviews():

```
getReviews: function(){
            let vm = this;
            axios.get('/datas/reviews?user='+ this.user + '&page='+ this.page)
            .then((response) =>{
                $.each(response.data.data, function(key, value) {
                                vm.reviews.push(value);
                                console.log((vm.reviews));
                        });
            })
            .catch(()=>{
            });
            this.page+=1;
        },
```

I've come up with this idea so that I will not use pagination anymore to view the next posts. It's more like a infinite scroll pagination component.